# Anyone used apex-atom?

Tags: apex

Has anybody used the [apex-atom](https://code.google.com/p/apex-atom) libraries? I think they were originally written by Dave Carroll but looks like they haven't been updated for about 4 years. We have a little point integration requirement around some older Atom feeds so it would be nice to be able to use these. They have so little documentation it's hard to tell if they're in working order. I'm happy to just install and take a stab at them but it would be even more helpful if someone has used them and can comment on their completeness / limitations / etc.

Comment: The last version I have is dated 8/30/2012 in terms of the source code, not the install version that's in the App Exchange. I recall downloading it from Github though. I've not done hardly anything with it to date and wouldn't expect it to utilize some of the more recent features of Apex with newer releases.

Comment: Thanks. My integration turned out to be so simple I could do what I needed with a couple basic regular expressions, so I ended up not using it.